# How to call a function when an URL has been entered into a UITextView in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call a function the moment a URL has been entered into an UITextView. I know about `textView.dataDetectorTypes = .link`, but is there a Delegate or something that will be fired the moment a link has been recognized?

I have checked `UITextViewDelegate`, but I wasn't able to find anything.

What are my options? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UITextViewDelegate` with `shouldChangeTextIn` method and check using `NSDataDetector`

Here is my working solution in Swift 3

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func checkURL(inputString: String) {
        let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
        let matches = detector.matches(in: inputString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: inputString.utf16.count))

        for match in matches {
            let url = (inputString as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
            print(url)
        }
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        checkURL(inputString: textView.text)
        return true
    }
}
```

Reference for `NSDataDetector` https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-detect-a-url-in-a-string-using-nsdatadetector

Comment: that's amazing. thank you so much for posting your solution. saves me so much time! and works great!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to listen for any changes to the text view (via the delegate) and then run it through `NSDataDetector` yourself: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatadetector

Comment: perfect! that was, what i was looking for. i'll try it out right now and will check answered once done. thank you very much